# ZigBee Gateway Clarification?

Tags: xbee, zigbee, arduino-uno, node-xbee, svd-xbee

I am working on setting up a project where I should be able to control my ZigBee End Device (ZDO or ZED) from an IP gateway. On having a detailed study, I understood on having a setup established.

However, I need to confirm if ZigBee devices from different vendors will be able communicate with each other?

If they can communicate, can a common (generic) Gateway be used for accessing or controlling the end devices (from different vendors) from a IP network?

Kindly lend me your suggestions. Also, your advice on the devices already available or how to progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the concept of a [ZigBee Gateway](https://docs.zigbee.org/zigbee-docs/dcn/09-5465.pdf) is to provide an IP interface to a ZigBee network.  All certified ZigBee devices of a given profile (Smart Energy, Home Automation, etc.) should be able to join a network that you can then access with a Gateway.

Just make sure you're using a [certified ZigBee Gateway](http://zigbee.org/Products/ByStandard/ZigBeeNetworkDevices.aspx).

Other companies, like [Digi International](http://www.digi.com/) make devices with IP and ZigBee interfaces that you may be able to use, if you're not interested in using the Gateway Standard.

Comment: Thanks tom..can you please explain a little more.. is there a common gateway in the market which can be used for both Home automation and smart metering ?? Has anyone implemented at the moment..if "yes", can you please share a link of the same ??

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is or not.  You would need to read up on each of the devices listed on the page I linked in my answer (under "certified ZigBee Gateway").